# How to change the order of a One2many field?

Tags: sorting, listview, odoo, odoo-view, one2many

I have a tree view, where the new items are placed above of all. Instead of that, I need to place the new item at the end of other items. Moreover, if the order of the new items is wrong I need to set them in the correct order

Where is this order configured? I need to change it

**Update**

> The "editable" property has two options are: top and bottom. I did not know the top choice then I thought I had configured `editable="bottom"` which was not correct. I just switched to bottom and it worked properly

Comment: I solved my problem by reading the documentation openerp. The "editable" property has two options are: top and bottom. I did not know the top choice then I thought I had configured editable = "bottom" which was not correct. I just switched to bottom and it worked properly.

It notes that the solution ChesuCR is successful if the order is wrong and the "editable" property is "bottom".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change the order of a tree or list you have mainly two options:

You can order the table using the attribute `_order` in your model. [Link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model._order)

```python
_order = "name, date_order desc"
```

If you are using Odoo v8-v15 you can add an attribute `default_order` in a specific tree view. [Link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#lists)

```xml
<tree default_order="sequence,name desc">
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: it helps me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: default_order does not work for v8 if tree is inside a Many2many field.

Comment: Sill does the job for Odoo v15.